# Unable to delete file after uploaded. (move_uploaded_file)

Tags: php, html, linux, apache, debian

Greetings anyone who is reading this!

Currently I have a php page that allows the user to upload a file to my server at a specified directory. Here is what I use to do that:

```
if(isset($_FILES['fileup']) && strlen($_FILES['fileup']['name']) > 1) {

chmod($uploadpath, 0777);

$uploadpath = $uploadpath . basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']);       // gets the file name
$sepext = explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['fileup']['name']));
$type = end($sepext);       // gets extension
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name']);     // gets image   width and height
$err = '';         // to store the errors


// If no errors, upload the image, else, output the errors
if($err == '') {
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'], $uploadpath)) { 
chmod($uploadpath, 0777);

  echo '<br/><br/>File successfully uploaded:' .$uploadpath.'</b>';

}
else echo  '<b>Unable to upload the file.</b>';
}
else echo $err;
}
```

The uploading part works like a charm and the file is uploaded fine to the server however once uploaded, I am unable to delete the file as another user. Currently the user uploading the file would be the Apache user "www-data".

I do believe that the issue has to do with permissions being set for the uploaded file which I have tried using:

```
chmod($uploadpath,0777);
```

This does not help though.. The file still can't be removed. I can remove it through SSH if I am root using "rm -rf /directorypath" but can't delete it if I browse to it.

Any suggestions? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

if you want to remove a file you can use php [unlink](http://www.php.net/unlink) ! And if thats a directory then [rmdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php)  !

Comment: Well I don't want to delete it with apache.. I have samba hosting as well. I want to be able to delete that file from another user other than apache's "www-data".

Answer (score 0):

you could use unlink('upload_folder/'.$image['file_name']);

Comment: Same reason as Pratik's answer, this will not help, but thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Try to allow permission to your image folder too not just the files underneath.

```
chmod($upload_path, 0777);
```

before the line

```
$uploadpath = $uploadpath . basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']);
```

Note that 777 is not super safe anyway. Best practice is to manage users with the group www-data

Comment: Yeah I realize it isn't the safest method. I was just trying to find something that worked. I will try this though and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Nope no luck :( It still won't let me delete the file.